# Is it possible to block a domain on linux without superuser access?

Tags: linux, networking, hosts-file, domain-name

The easiest way I know to block a domain is to go add something like this to my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    facebook.com
```

Boom, done.

But I have to be a superuser. Which is a bit annoying, because I would like to not have to be a superuser.

Is there a simple way to do this on linux, or would I have to do something painful like add a proxy server?

Comment: Use `sudo` to temporarily become a superuser and edit /etc/hosts. After the edit, you are back to "normal", so no annoyance. Every other way to "block a domain" is much more painful.

Comment: Just for me and my user. Really what I want to do is disable giphy when I'm using my phone hotspot because holy crap that sucks a lot of bandwidth. Seems like the easiest way would be toggle it on and off on my computer...

Comment: There are plenty of Chrome/Firefox extensions to block sites in your browser (AdblockPlus and more specialized apps).